# richfaces 4.2.1.Final not working with jetty 8

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Richfaces 4.2.1.Final is out and i am trying to use it with jetty 8, as doc of richfaces itself says it is compatible with jetty 8 but having errors while deploying..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:951)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:302)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:456)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:276)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:779)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:888)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$Registration.addMapping(ServletHolder.java:621)
at org.richfaces.webapp.ResourceServletContainerInitializer.registerServlet(ResourceServletContainerInitializer.java:67)
at org.richfaces.webapp.ResourceServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(ResourceServletContainerInitializer.java:57)
at org.richfaces.webapp.RichFacesServletsInitializer.onStartup(RichFacesServletsInitializer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializerListener.contextInitialized(ServletContainerInitializerListener.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:672)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:664)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:239)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1212)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:546)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1203)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1126)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:469)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:612)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use latest Jetty 8 build. As of my writing, the latest build is 8.1.3.v20120416.
I also had the similar issue with Jetty 8.0.x. After upgrading Jetty it worked without any problem.

Comment: thanks.. it works completely fine.

before i tried this build but there was some other errors so could not able to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

> MyFaces and Mojarra register a servlet context listener for the startup configuration via the TLD file of the JSF core taglib. So far this has worked without problems on most containers but it does no longer work on Jetty 8. The reason for this is, that Jetty 8 uses the Glassfish JSP implementation which requires the TLD files to be on the classpath of the container. This is not the case if the application is started via the Jetty Maven Plugin and the above exception is thrown.

See here: http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/jsf-2-on-jetty-8/